# how to publish website using cmd

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, cmd, publishing

is it possible to replicate this using cmd in c#

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're just talking about pushing content up to a site, I'm working on such a beast now.

My proof-of-concept used a `Process` object to simply run a `cmd.exe` script that used FTP:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
:
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "myUpload.cmd";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

The program published the web site (it wasn't an actual web site but similar enough that the same method can be used) locally and used the browser to open the file (this was static content only so no need for a web server).

Then, once validated by the user, it simply created a script file `temp.ftp` containing all the relevant commands and used `ftp -s:temp.ftp -n test.com` within `myUpload.cmd` to do the file transfer. The `-s` specifies the script to run and the `-n` stops automatic login. That's so you can dynamically create a `user` command in your script to log in.

The final version will actually probably run Python code so I don't have to fight the brain-deadedness of `cmd.exe` but the theory is the same.